# If table doesn't exists then insert into other table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have procedure like:

```
create or replace procedure smth
is
some_variable varchar(2;
begin

insert into **table**(col1,col2) (Select id,'text' from TABLE2),
insert into table(col1,col2) (Select id,'text' from TABLE3)
```

What I want to do is put some if-else (or smoething else) statement for the case when eg. Table2 doesn't exists.
If Table2 doesn't exist then insert into **table** ('smth','nameoftable') from DUAL. I know exactly what is the name of the table2. ( but for some reason this table could be deleted from database).

It would be great if I could do that this way:

```
insert into **table**(col1,col2) if table2 doesn't exist then Select (1,'TABLE2') else (Select id,'text' from TABLE2),

if table3 doesn't exist then Select (1,'TABLE3') insert into table(col1,col2)  else (Select id,'text' from TABLE3)
```

For each case.

### EDIT

```
 insert into **table**(col1,col2) (Select id,'text' from TABLE2),
    insert into table(col1,col2) (Select id,'text' from TABLE3)
    insert into table(col1,col2) (Select id,'text' from TABLE4)
    insert into table(col1,col2) (Select id,'text' from TABLE4)
```

Assume that table3 doesn't EXIST, then all what I want is INSERT into table ( Select 'text','text2' from dual.

Comment: This is a *very* strange case; a table not being there, then simply using another table. With the INSERT statement in your stored procedure, your procedure would become invalid when the table gets deleted. Hence you need dynamic SQL instead, so the DBMS doesn't see that the table is used inside the procedure.

Comment: Hello, I did not said precisly what i'm expecting.If table doesn't exist then insert 'text',text2' FROM DUAL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get waht you want you need two things

1. Find if the table exists: you can query the `user_tables` against the
   `table_name` column if the procedure is reading form the table in the
   same schema
2. you need to use dynamic sql because if the table does not exists
   with static pl/sql you get the error **PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or
       view does not exists** because when oracle compiles the procedure it
   does not find the table.

An example of dynamic plsql is

```
 sql_stmt := 'insert into table(col1,col2) (Select id,''text'' from ' || <the right table_name> || ')';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
```

Here is a link to the oracle documentation for [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011).

**EDIT**
After you clarification can end with a procedure like this one:

```
  create or replace procedure insert_from_dual_if_not_exists(table_name_in in varchar2)    
    begin
    .....
    if table_exists('<table_name>') then
    sql_stmt := 'insert into table(col1,col2)' (Select id,''text'' from ' || <the right table_name> || ')';
    else
    sql_stmt := 'insert into table(col1,col2)' (Select ''text1'',''text2'' from dual )';
    end if;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
    end;
```

and call `insert_from_dual_if_not_exists` instead of you simple insert; you must also create a procedure (or a simple statement) that telle your code if a table exists.

Comment: Hello, I did not said precisly what i'm expecting.If table doesn't exist then insert 'text',text2' FROM DUAL

Answer (score 1):

You could query the **USER_TABLES** view to see whether the table actually exists or not. And, you must (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** to execute the dynamic sql.

For example,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO   v_cnt 
FROM   USER_TABLES 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE_1>';

v_sql := INSERT INTO TABLE(col1,col2).. SELECT id,'text'  FROM ';

IF v_cnt > 0
THEN
   v:sql := v_sql || TABLE_1;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
ELSE
   v:sql := v_sql || TABLE_2;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END IF;
```

**UPDATE** OP wants to dynamically use the table_name to insert into another table from multiple tables.

Loop through all the tables, and use the table_name as a variable in the dynamic sql.

For example,

```
FOR i IN SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name <> 'inserting_table'
LOOP
   v_sql := 'INSERT INTO inserting_table SELECT column_list FROM' || i.table_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: It would works, but i have too many tables ( around 20-25 ), then i have to repeat that code for every table. I have to insert everything into 1 table, but FROM around 20-25 tables (some of them could do not exist...). I did not said precisly but If table doesn't exist then I want insert into TABLE ('text','1') - some explicit data.

Comment: once again,I did some mistake. : If table doesn't exist then insert 'text',text2' FROM DUAL

Comment: This won't work.  If `table_1` doesn't exist, your block won't compile.  The code would only compile if both `table_1` and `table_2` existed.  You'd need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @maciek2791 In that case you need to loop through all those tables using dynamic sql. See the update.

Comment: @JustinCave True, it would throw compilation error with static sql. Edited to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this kind of procedure executing dynamic sql that contains anonymouse block and catching exception with `sqlcode`

```
create or replace procedure testproc
is 
v_sql varchar2(4000) := q'[
declare
begin
 insert into table3 values(1,2);
end;]';
begin
execute immediate v_sql;
exception when others
  then if
sqlcode='-6550' then 
 insert into **table** values()
end if;
 end testproc;
```